What is this PSU connector? Compaq Portable motherboard
I've lost the PSU wiring harness to my Compaq Portable motherboard in a move and I'm trying to figure out what connector this is. Here's a picture with some AT-era Molex connectors for perspective.
Pins are ~0.8mm diameter, ~3.8mm spacing center-to-center.
[edit 2] 3.81mm is .150", so maybe it's Imperial units.
[edit 3] ChatGPT suggested the Compaq portable used a proprietary connector made by AMP (now owned by TC so AMP/TC). I found one example of a 6-pin header made by amp in 3.81mm, but no connector. Also, I just realized my pictures obscured that there are notches in the connector (see the PSU pic)
https://www.digikey.ph/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/87221-5/2273451
[edit] added picture of similar model PSU from online



The connector in itself is nothing remarkable - it's pretty generic. I have a handful of similar connectors (but 2.54mm/0.1in pitch); they're used for ad hoc board to board connectivity.  Do you know for sure that it's related to the PSU?

Yes, it goes straight and only to the PSU.

Can you get a better picture of what is written next to the connector? The one in the middle seems to be "GND", the one on the left starts with 5 (5V?), so possibly you have labels for all the pins...

And 3.81mm connectors seem still to be available, just search your favorite electronics supply website.

What's on the PSU end of this?  Presumably nothing so simple as a 14-pin header, otherwise a straight-through ribbon cable would be most likely.

I wouldn't plug in the bus until I see the pinouts.Sites have that for everything.  Don't guess. And keep those drive connectors away from that board! They power the drives. Power to the peripherals! Join the symbiont liberation army!

The other end of those drive connectors come from the pwr supply. Is there another cable for the board power? If not, there MUST be a socket for it.

I'm not worried about the pinout itself. It's mostly standard 5v, 12v, GND,-5v stuff I can re-trace later. I could easily wire it myself, but I'd be super annoyed if destroy the original connector and later find the original wiring harness. So I'm trying to find whatever connector they used. ChatGPT (which can be wrong) thought it was an "AMP/TE" designed connector (AMP company being later bought by TE). But I haven't found the connector online.

The difficulty seems to be the 0.15" pitch. There are a bazillion 1x14 connectors with 0.1" pitch.

“ChatGPT (which can be wrong)” is surely the politest way I’ve ever heard it described.

That said, ChatGPT guessing AMP/TE wouldn't be worse than your average human with a "must save face" complex. AMP designed that "Molex" connector you're holding for scale. I'd also expect to see Molex, given they cloned it and then created the "ATX power supply motherboard connector". (According to Wikipedia, that one is called a "Molex Mini-Fit Jr.") I'll search around and see if I can find anything useful to give as a proper answer.

@dirkt - on 3.81mm connector availability. I've looked around a couple of places and failed to find what I think is called for: a 1x14 female 3.81mm connector that can be attached to a ribbon cable.  Did you find one?  I saw board-mounted female connectors, but no cable-mounted.

E.g. mouser which leads to this, though it's not directly a ribbon cable, you have to screw each line separately. I am sure there are more, I just did a quick search.
